# Acceptance behavior of L and NL with and without cycling

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

The complexity class NL seems to allow cycling, otherwise we wouldn't have SL $\subset$ NL. What about L? If an algorithm from L cycles for a given input, it certainly cannot accept (because it won't enter the accepting state), so we could define that it rejects in this case (which would be consistent with NL). Or is cycling simply not allowed for L?

Does this makes any difference at all, i.e. would NL or L get weaker (in the sense that we can't prove that they still accept the same languages), if we would completely forbid cycling?

Comment: What do you mean by "cycling"? Do you mean that the TM repeats a configuration? If so, it can always be avoided by keeping a (logspace) counter for the maximal number of configurations, and halting when the counter resets.

Comment: @Shaull Exactly. The idea with the counter answers this question. So one can allow or forbid cycling on a case by case decision, whatever is more convenient for the specific case.

Comment: I do not understand why you seem to claim that an NDTM deciding (for instance) STCON must cycle.  Yes, for a YES instance there will be accepting runs where a configuration is repeated if one uses a trivial NDTM that tracks the current vertex and guesses which successor to go to next.  However, there is then always an accepting run without a repeated configuration, by removing the parts of the run that loop.  In other words, if there is an accepting run, then there is an accepting run that does not repeat the machine configuration.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon You may also interpret "NL seems to allow cycling" as "it seems that we may allow NL to contain machines which cycle for certain inputs". The reasoning behind the entire sentence is simple. If allowing cycling for NL would be problematic, this issue would be discussed in much more detail when talking about SL $\subset$ NL. The straightforward definition of SL involves machines for which cycling is the rule rather than the exception.

Comment: I still do not understand your contention.  If there is an accepting run of an NDTM, then there is an accepting run that does not repeat any machine configuration.  SL is contained in NL because it imposes an additional condition on the transition relation of the NDTM.  Where is the cycling?

Comment: @AndrásSalamon "A [symmetric Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_Turing_machine) is a Turing machine which has a configuration graph that is undirected (that is, configuration i yields configuration j if and only if j yields i)." So by definition, this sort of Turing machine can visit any already visited configuration again, and again, and ... Do you agree that the "additional condition on the transition relation" is very closely related to cycling?

Comment: A symmetric TM is an NDTM for which the transition relation is also symmetric.  A configuration of a TM includes not just the internal state and head positions, but also the contents of the worktape.  You appear to be calling repeating a state "cycling", and are possibly calling states "configurations", whereas @Shaull and I understood cycling to refer to repeating configurations.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon If a NDTM can repeat a configuration (not just an internal state), then it can repeat the corresponding sequence of steps (which lead to the repetition) infinitely often. This is why I call this cycling. Your comments are unclear whether you want to criticize a lazy use of language (""cycling") from my part, whether you think I misunderstand something ("claim", "contention", "you appear to be calling..."), or whether you are misunderstanding something. That's why I asked "Do you agree ... related to cycling?", because I hoped your answer would clarify this.

Comment: Trying to answer your question: whether a TM can repeat a configuration or not seems unrelated to symmetry in the transition relation.  Most DFAs repeat configurations, whether their transition relations are symmetric or not.  We could define NDTM acceptance as "there exists an accepting run which contains no repeated configuration" and have exactly the same classes of languages accepted by NDTMs.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I see. I think you misunderstand the intention behind symmetric Turing machines, because you think of it as some rather technical condition on the transition relation that doesn't really mean anything. The intention is that the machine can reverse any step, which also includes reversing the position on the input tape (which DFAs cannot do).  This is the important point, independent of whether I or the wikipedia page used the word "configuration" fully correct or not.

Comment: A DFA can be regarded as a (really trivial) TM.  I am simply saying that _really trivial_ DTMs cycle, as a matter of course, apropos your sentence about cycling for L.  Symmetry in the transition relation may or may not be a technical condition (Reingold showed SL=L, so symmetry isn't as interesting as it may have appeared in LP1982).  However, symmetry means that formally every symmetric TM is a special kind of NDTM, by definition, regardless of cycling or any other apparent emergent behaviour.  A focus on cycling seems to be focusing on the wrong part of what makes these systems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaull's comment answers the question:

> Do you mean that the TM repeats a configuration? If so, it can always be avoided by keeping a (logspace) counter for the maximal number of configurations, and halting when the counter resets.

This technique can even be used, without knowing (beforehand) any bound for the amount of space used. The TM can just keep track of the amount of space used till the current step (excluding the additional counter), and halt when the counter exceeds the maximal possible number of different configurations given the space used.

The additional counter will take the same amount of space as the computation already used plus the logarithm of the length of the input already scanned. Tracking of the amount of space used adds the logarithm of that used space to the total used space. So this approach to detect (avoid) repeated configurations works for any non-sublogarithmic space complexity class.

---

When I asked that question, I had in mind a technique for finding cycles which only works for deterministic machines: I take two copies of the machine, and always perform one step for the first machine and two steps for the second machine, and then compare the configurations of the two machines. Those configurations can only be equal if the machines cycles, and any cycle will be found before the first machine repeats a configuration.

This technique only works for deterministic machines, and only when copying the machine doesn't violate any resource restrictions. For example, it doesn't work for stack machines (because having two stacks is fundamentally different from having only one stack), and it doesn't work for machines which may only read their input once.

---

For machines which can read their input only in forward direction and only once, the above two techniques can be slightly modified. Each time a new symbol from the input is read, the entire machinery for detection of repeated configurations is reset, and starts again from zero. So the input position must no longer be included in the number of possible states, and the copied machines (of the second technique) no longer need any access to the input. This allows to apply those techniques also to DFAs.

Similar modifications to also make those techniques applicable to stack machines would be nice, because we know that PDAs have no problems with repeated configurations either.

Comment: Keeping a counter doesn't _avoid_ cycling, it just ensures that cycles are detected and those runs are terminated early.  This is a useful technical device when dealing with time-bounded classes, to make sure that a machine can't cycle beyond the polynomial time bound to reach an accepting state, but is not necessary for space-bounded classes.  Further, adding a logarithmic counter to a TM means it always uses at least logarithmic space, even if the language it accepts is regular, so is usually avoided when studying classes below L.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon The machine which includes the counter and tracks the used space of the original machine is a different machine than the original machine. This machine still satisfies the resource restrictions, doesn't cycle (because the counter is part of the configuration), and still gives the same answer as the original machine. Cool, no?

Comment: "Logarithm of the length of the input already scanned" forces at least logarithmic space to be used, even when this isn't necessary, as for a DFA recognizing a regular language.  The new machine only satisfies resource restrictions that allow at least logarithmic space.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon The interesting fact is that cycling can be avoided for DFA and NFA, only the two techniques described in this answer won't work for that case. (They won't work for PDAs either, which is more sad. But one can't have everything.)